# Huge chars data is not going through ajax call to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

huge chars data is not going through ajax call and I can able to see the chars in request body in browsers debug tools. If I send few chars I can able to receive it in server side!!

ajax call :

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : "/RegisterServlet_2/servlet/Register",
        type : "POST",
        data: "img="+compressed,
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        success : function()
        {
        },
        error : function()
        {
        }
    });
```

Fyi, I don't want to send as json object. I just want to send as string only!
Any way out? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove the java tag

Comment: You could try splitting the string and sending many Ajax calls

Comment: Why don't you want to send it as json? You could simply de-code the json on the server side?

Comment: json will do automatic encoding on jquery which I don't want!!